# What happens to the attribute when a page reloads?

Tags: jsp, cookies

When I come to a jsp page(A), first I check if a particular attribute is present in the request. If present, I set a cookie accordingly. So if a user logs on for the first time, there will obviously be no attribute in the request and so the cookie will not be set.
 But when the user comes from another jsp(say B) where the attribute has been set in the response, then the cookie will be set. After one such series of events has taken place, if I go to the jsp page A directly from the url, still a new cookie has been set. How can this happen.Because now there should not be any attribute as I am going directly to page A.
This is my code.

```
String level=(String) request.getAttribute("level");

 if(level!=null)
 {
  Cookie cookie=new Cookie("level",level);
  cookie.setMaxAge(60*2);
  cookie.setPath("/");
  response.addCookie(cookie);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set a cookie on the client (browser) by sending it in the response, it will always be sent along with every request to your site as long as the path defined in the cookie matches the URL and the cookie  is not expired, even if the user closes the browser, restarts it and accesses the URL of your site

In your example, you are setting the path to "/" so cookie will be sent with *every* URL.

If you want your cookies to be sent only for specific subset of the URL, set the path attribute accordingly. From the cookie spec at http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html:

> The path attribute is used to specify the subset of URLs in a domain
>   for which the cookie is valid. If a cookie has already passed domain
>   matching, then the pathname component of the URL is compared with the
>   path attribute, and if there is a match, the cookie is considered
>   valid and is sent along with the URL request. The path "/foo" would
>   match "/foobar" and "/foo/bar.html". The path "/" is the most general
>   path. If the path is not specified, it as assumed to be the same path
>   as the document being described by the header which contains the
>   cookie.

Also note that cookie is stored in the filesystem of the client machine, so it persists across browser restarts - it will be sent along with the request even if browser is restarted and your URL is accessed, as long as cookie is not expired and other security rules apply

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I don't think you read my question properly. My quetion is why a new cookie set each time in my scenario.

Comment: what do you mean by a 'new cookie'? are you losing the value of the cookie with multiple requests? you can examine the local cookies in your browser to ensure cookie is being currently set. If you can provide more details on the cookie value you are setting, what gets stored in the browser, and what gets passed with the request (you can examine the Net tab in firebug to see the cookies being passed to the server) that will be helpful in diagnosing

Comment: By new cookie I mean that the cookies expiry time extends each time I refresh the page.

Comment: ok - so request attributes get rest with every new request. So you will not have anything in request attributes whenever a URL is accessed again. However, your server will have access to the cookie - so you can perhaps check the existence of the cookie instead of checking request attribute by using request.getCookie(). See http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Cookies.html. I guess your problem is that you are resending the cookie with every response even though you do not intend to do that

Comment: I will try the method you suggested. But what is wrong with the current method. If request attributes get rest with every new request, then how come a cookie is being sent with every response. Because the cookies will be sent with the response only if the request attribute is not null. Please see the code.

Comment: It is not clear how, in the first request you are causing the attribute to be  not-null. Please look at the place where you are setting the attribute - i suspect the setting is happening for both the first request and any subsequent request too

Comment: can attributes be sent using a sendRedirect() method in a servlet(attributes not paramaters)

Comment: No - because redirect will cause a new request to be created. However,  you can look into using a forward instead of a redirect if you wish to communicate between servlets (the request parameters and attributes are preserved since it is the same request) - and it also saves roundtrip to the client

Comment: No what I am saying is that I want to set new attributes and then redirect. Is this possible? I am not asking if the old attributes will be preserved when new requests are made.

Comment: all attributes are lost when you redirect.

Comment: okay.. So what should I do if I want to send a large object from one domain to another. I cannot use forward. Redirect is the only option - but only redirect get requests can be sent using redirect. Is there any other option or any other method?

Comment: so on the server, if you want to communicate with another server on another domain, using a library such as httpclient is the way to go: http://hc.apache.org/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10262/discussion-between-ashwin-and-vijay-agrawal)

Comment: there is not example code or a sample to code there to indicate its usage. Can I do perform a HttpURLConnection from one servlet, and send/receive data to/from another server?

Comment: example code is available at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html see the first link